# JavaFX Add Panels Dynamically

Tags: java, javafx

Ok so I've been working with JavaFX since some days ago.
First of all, I tried a lot of stuff to find a kind of "tab" which would be selectable to then show a specific Panel when it's selected, tried with a normal `TabPanel` but making the tabs bigger and making them vertically, and tried to rotate the text by using labels but I also had icons and well... It was just complicated and didn't look as good.

I solved that my own way, by using normal `AnchorPanes` and event listeners.
Basically when I click a tab it turns it a little bit gray, everything okay by here (even if it's not what I really wanted, just a quick fix).

But the problem comes here: let's say I have my application showing the main menu and I want it to display another pane when I have a specific tab selected, how do I do that? I tried with an `EventListener` when you click it, and call `Stage#setScene`, but that would completely change the scene. Thanks

Comment: Consider splitting this question. You're first describing things that are not really relevant for *this* question.

Comment: To make things clearer consider removing unnecessary background  information and focus on the question. Code would be more helpful, [mcve] would be best

Comment: I'm pretty sure you gave up on using ***`TabPane`*** too soon. `TabPane.setSide` to make the `TabPane` vertical. If necessary a pane can be used as `Tab.grapic` to display unrotated text and some graphic. What you're trying to do seems like reinventing the wheel to me...

Comment: Hmmm... Yeah, I tried using setSide and also adding graphics. I added a label to it but I also needed an image, and when I added the image it was kinda overlapped for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not change the Scene, you would swap out the children of a Parent class (e.g. a Pane or Group).

Lets say you have a Parent called `content`.   `content` could be a Group or a Pane, like GridPane or BorderPane or etc.  Now for each tab you can have a corresponding content Node that will be set into the `content`.

Assume you have the following objects:

```
AnchorPane tabDetails = ....;
AnchorPane tabAccountInfo = ....;
AnchorPane tabContactUs = ....;
Node contentDetails = ....;
Node contentAccountInfo = ....;
Node contentContactUs = ....;
Parent content = ....;
```

How you get your tabs and Parent `content` objects on the screen is beyond the scope fo this answer, you will have to decide how you get those objects on the screen, for example you can use a BorderPane or GridPane or conbination of Panes (like HBox to place the tabs in the Top position of a BorderPane and the BorderPane can go into the Scene).  Up to you.

Here is the code for swapping out the content if a tab is clicked on.

```
tabDetails.setOnMouseClicked(me -> content.getChildren().setAll(contentDetails));
tabAccountInfo.setOnMouseClicked(me -> content.getChildren().setAll(contentAccountInfo));
tabContactUs.setOnMouseClicked(me -> content.getChildren().setAll(contentContactUs));
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! This worked for me.
By the way, is there any way to have some sort of ListView that could list elements like this in a ScrollPane? For example:

| Version | Name
| 0.0.0     | Application name

Comment: Look at ScrolPane as a wrapper to whatever Node you want.  So in this case you would not list items into a ScrolPane but you would list them into the Node contained within the ScrolPane.  Take a look at HBox or VBox.

Comment: Thank you. One last question, I tried using a TabPane and Tabs now since it looks easier, but I have a small problem, to make it so I could rotate a Label and also put an image (which I couldn't do with setGraphic since it's only one) I did setGraphic with a StackPane containing the Label and the image as I saw somebody did it too in this site... My problem is that if I put the image fit width and height more than around 20, the tab would turn really small and buggy. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: You can put the Label to have a big enough prefHeight so that when you rotate it, it will take up more than 20 pixels.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. Just solved the problem on another StackOverflow question. Anyways, thanks for the help :D